# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: users for class: Script1

Tags: java, maven, groovy

In my Java code, I am trying to invoke the Eval.me Groovy method (using Apache Groovy maven dependency) to evaluate a string expression. But I am getting this exception:

`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: users for class: Script1`

I get the error on this line

`Eval.me("id", id, "/users/id")`

Trying to evaluate "/users/id" by making the parameter (id) available inside the script

What I am essentialy trying to do is given the value of an id, I want to evaluate the path (/users/id) to retrieve a specific user.

```
public String getUser(String id, String expression){
String getUserPath = Eval.me("id", id, expression).toString();
return getUserPath; 
}
```

^ Here expression would be "/users/id"

Eval.me is defined under [groovy.util.Eval](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html#me(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String))

I am expecting that the expression gets evaluated to "/users/123" if 123 is the value of the id parameter.

What could I be doing wrong and how can I go about carrying this out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/users/123` is not a valid java/groovy code

Comment: Also `users` is not defined variable.

Comment: The third parameter of `Eval.me()` mus be a legal groovy expression. As for your problem, you may use `expression.replace('id', id)`, and the regular expression solutions may be required if the expression is more complex.